# Can I Use Ninject To Bind A Boolean Value To A Named Constructor Value

Tags: ninject

I have a constructor such as:

```cs
public AnalyticsController(ClassA classA, ClassB classB, bool isLiveEnvironment)
{
   ...
}
```

`isLiveEnvironment` is determined using a call to an existing static class such as:

```cs
MultiTenancyDetection.GetInstance().IsLive();
```

I would like to be able to make this call outside of the controller and inject the result into isLiveEnvironment.  Is this possible?  I can not see how this can be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this using `WithConstructorArgument` and using a callback:

```cs
kernel.Bind<AnalyticsController>()
      .ToSelf()
      .WithConstructorArgument("isLiveEnvironment", ctx => MultiTenancyDetection.GetInstance().IsLive() );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even achieve this more generally (but i would not really recommend binding such a generic type for such a specific use case):

```cs
IBindingRoot.Bind<bool>().ToMethod(x => MultiTenancyDetection.GetInstance().IsLive())
    .When(x => x.Target.Name == "isLiveEnvironment");
```

Alternatively, if you need the same configuration value in several / a lot of classes, create an interface for it:

```cs
public interface IEnvironment
{
    bool IsLive { get; }
}

internal class Environment : IEnvironment
{
    public bool IsLive
    {
        get
        {
            return MultiTenancyDetection.GetInstance().IsLive();
        }
    }
}

IBindingRoot.Bind<IEnvironment>().To<Environment>();
```

Comment: +1 I like the `IEnvironment` approach, seems very clean.